# Inclusion relationship $(\mathfrak{a}:\mathfrak{b})\mathfrak{b} \subset \mathfrak{a} \cap \mathfrak{b}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unit and $\mathfrak{a},\mathfrak{b}$ be ideals of $R$. I had the inclusion relationship

$(\mathfrak{a}:\mathfrak{b})\mathfrak{b} \subset \mathfrak{a} \cap \mathfrak{b}$,

where $(\mathfrak{a}:\mathfrak{b})$ is the ideal quotient. I derived that the reverse relation holds in some examples, but I can't prove it for any $R,\mathfrak{a},\mathfrak{b}$.

Would you have any ideas or hints for the proof? If the reverse does not hold, what counterexmaples exist?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example. Let $R = \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ and $I = (y), J = (xy, x+1)$. Then $(y:(xy,x+1)) = (y)$ since $x+1$ and $y$ are coprime. We compute $(y)\cdot (xy,x+1) = (xy^2,y(x+1)) = (y^2,y(x+1)),$ but $(y)\cap (xy,x+1) = (xy,y(x+1)) = (y)$.

I would have suspected that this cannot be an equality in general from the fact that $\frak{a}\cdot\frak{b} \neq \frak{a}\cap \frak{b}$ in general, although in the coprime case then $(\frak{a}:\frak{b}) = \frak{a}$ and we do get equality. I don't know of any general condition under which we do get equality.